# If three nonzero real matrices mutually anticommute, then at least one of them has a negative off-diagonal element

Tags: matrices, clifford-algebras

The following is a statement which I believe to be correct but unable to prove (I have been trying to find a counterexample for a long time but never succeeded in doing so):

**Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be $n\times n$ nonzero real matrices satisfying $X_{i}X_j=-X_jX_i\neq 0$ for $1\leq i<j\leq 3$ [as an example, $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}=\{\sigma^x,i\sigma^y,\sigma^z\}$, the [Pauli-matrices]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Prove that at least one of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ has a negative off-diagonal element.**

The case $n=2$ is easy and straightforward: just expand $X_1,X_2,X_3$ in the basis of Pauli matrices and solve the equation $\{X_i,X_j\}=0$. But when $n$ becomes large, the coupled quadratic equations quickly becomes formidable, which I have no way to handle.

Notice also that the $\neq 0$ condition is important, otherwise we got a simple counter-example: $X_1=X_2=X_3=\sigma^+$, which mutually anti-commute but are all non-negative.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hi Noah, thanks for your comment. This problem arose in my theoretical physics research and it has puzzled me for more than one year up to now. It's definitely not a homework problem. I just simply have no idea how to prove it--I tried to write out all the components, but it leads to coupled quadratic equations, which I have no way to handle. Notice that the diagonal elements are allowed to be negative. If you think it's too easy or even stupid, please leave a hint for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lagrenge You should clarifications like this in the body of the question, not the comments.  People browsing the questions won't see the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true, at least when the matrices are allowed to be singular. Let
$$
D=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1},
\ S=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}.
$$
Then $DS$ and $SD$ are nonzero but $DS+SD=0$. The following set of matrices now serves as a counterexample to your statement:
$$
X_1=\pmatrix{D\\ &D\\ &&0},
\ X_2=\pmatrix{S\\ &0\\ &&D},
\ X_3=\pmatrix{0\\ &S\\ &&S}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just a start.  As you say, the coupled quadratic equations seem impossible to deal with, but I think we can make progress proceeding by contradiction.

It's easy to prove that not all the off-diagonal elements can be strictly positive.  Assume, on the contrary, that they are.

Let the three matrices be $$A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n},\,B=(b_{ij})_{n\times n},\,C=(c_{ij})_{n\times n}$$

For $1\leq i\leq n,$ we have $$\begin{align}
\left(AB\right)_{ii}&=a_{ii}b_{ii}+\sum_{k\neq i}a_{ik}b_{ki}\tag{1}\\
\left(BA\right)_{ii}&=b_{ii}a_{ii}+\sum_{k\neq i}b_{ik}a_{ki}
\end{align}$$

Since both sums are strictly positive, in order that $\left(AB\right)_{ii}= -\left(BA\right)_{ii}$, $a_{ii}$ and $b_{ii}$ must have opposite signs.  But the same is true of $a_{ii}$ and $c_{ii}$ and of $b_{ii}$ and $c_{ii}$, and this is clearly impossible.

Now consider the case where all the off-diagonal elements in the three matrices are nonnegative.  Proceeding as in $(1)$, we see that either $a_{ii}$ and $b_{ii}$ have opposite signs, or at least one of them is $0$.  Then at least one of $a_{ii}, b_{ii}, c_{ii}$ is $0$, as above.  Suppose that $a_{ii}=0$.  Then both sums in $(1)$ must be $0$, so that for $k\ne i$ at least one of $a_{ik},\, b_{ki}$ is $0$ and at least one of $b_{ik},\, a_{ki}$ is $0$.  Of course, a similar statement holds with $B$ in place of $C$.

We see that a counterexample will have a lot of $0$ elements.  My thought is to either show that there are so many $0$s that one of the matrix products must be $\mathbf{0}$, or to eliminate so many variables that it's possible to find a counterexample.

I've been trying to exploit the facts above to the equation $\left(AB\right)_{ij}=-\left(AB\right)_{ij}$ when $i\neq j,$ but it's a liitle more complicated.

I think the basic problem is to find a compact way to express the facts about the positions of the $0$s that will lend itself to further computation easily, but so far, I haven't gotten anywhere.